# change height and width of buttons in buttonset jquery

Tags: jquery, button, height

Is there a way to make the jQuery buttonset buttons smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to preset the height on the elements. e.g

$('.selector').css('width','20px').buttonset();

so the style attribute changes before it's a button.